# Synonyms for words by Levenshtein Distance

Tags: c#, levenshtein-distance, synonym

This is my code:

```
public void SearchWordSynonymsByLevenstein()
{
    foreach (var eachWord in wordCounter)
    {
        foreach (var eachSecondWord in wordCounter)
        {
            if (eachWord.Key.Length > 3)
            {
                var score = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(eachWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Key);
                if (score < 2)
                {
                    if(!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Any(x => x.Value.ContainsKey(eachSecondWord.Key)))
                    {
                        if (!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.ContainsKey(eachWord.Key))
                        {
                            wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Add(eachWord.Key, new Dictionary<string, int> { { eachSecondWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Value } });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            wordSynonymsByLevenstein[eachWord.Key].Add(eachSecondWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My `wordCounter` is `Dictionary<string, int>` where key is my each word and value is count how many this word exists in documents. Something like Bag of word. I must search synonyms for `eachWord` from other `eachSecondWord`. This method cost too much time. Time increases exponentially. There is other way to reduce the time ?

Comment: Does `wordSynonymsByLevenstein` really need to be a `Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string, int>>`? Why not just a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>`?  You can use that to find the "synonyms" then go to `wordCounter` for the counts.

Comment: Thanks, later I'm doing this:
`if (wordSynonymsByLevenstein.TryGetValue(eachMainWord, out isThisWord))
{
 foreach (var eachWw in isThisWord)
 {
  mainWordWithSynonyms.Add(eachWw.Key);
  fullCounted = fullCounted + eachWw.Value;
 }
 var distinctedWord = mainWordWithSynonyms.DistinctBy(x => x).ToList();
 if (mainFoundWords.Any(x => distinctedWord.Any(y => y == x)) && compFoundWords.Any(x => distinctedWord.Any(y => y == x)))
 {
  relationScore = relationScore + ((double)1 / (double)fullCounted);
  countedEqualWord++;
 }
}` So `wordSynonymsByLevenshtein` must be this `Dictionary`

Comment: What I'm saying is that if `wordSynonymsByLevenstein` is a `Dictionary<string, List<string>` then you'd get the `isThisWord` out and it would be the list of words, so change `eachWw.Key` to `eachWw` and `eachWw.Value` to `wordCounter[eachWw]`

Comment: Also I'm wondering why you do `if(!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Any(x => x.Value.ContainsKey(eachSecondWord.Key)))`.  Are you saying you don't want to associate a word to more than one other word.  So if you had "foobar, foobak, and foobal".  You'd want to associate foobar -> foobak, foobar -> foobal, foobak -> foobar, but not the following foobak -> foobal, foobal -> foobar, foobal -> foobak?  That's assumming you don't actually want foobar -> foobar, foobar -< foobak, foobar -> foobal, which is what your code currently does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I assume you don't want to associate a word with itself in the `wordSynonymsByLevenstein` collection.  Second you can skip ones that you know will not meet your < 2 score requirement by comparing the lengths of the words.

```
public void SearchWordSynonymsByLevenstein()
{
    foreach (var eachWord in wordCounter)
    {
        foreach (var eachSecondWord in wordCounter)
        {
            if (eachWord.Key == eachSecondWord.Key 
                || eachWord.Key.Length <= 3 
                || Math.Abs(eachWord.Key.Length - eachSecondWord.Key.Length) >= 2)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var score = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(eachWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Key);
            if (score >= 2)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Any(x => x.Value.ContainsKey(eachSecondWord.Key)))
            {
                if (!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.ContainsKey(eachWord.Key))
                {
                    wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Add(eachWord.Key, new Dictionary<string, int> { { eachSecondWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Value } });
                }
                else
                {
                    wordSynonymsByLevenstein[eachWord.Key].Add(eachSecondWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Value);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Your requirement that is expressed with the `if(!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Any(x => x.Value.ContainsKey(eachSecondWord.Key)))` is not particularly obvious or straight forward, but if you don't want a word associated with more than one, then you could additionally add a `HashSet<string>` and as you associate words add them to that `HashSet` and check if the next word is in there before continuing, instead of iterating the nested dictionaries.

```
public void SearchWordSynonymsByLevenstein()
{
    var used = new HashSet<string>();
    foreach (var eachWord in wordCounter)
    {
        foreach (var eachSecondWord in wordCounter)
        {
            if (eachWord.Key == eachSecondWord.Key 
                || eachWord.Key.Length <= 3 
                || Math.Abs(eachWord.Key.Length - eachSecondWord.Key.Length) >= 2)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var score = LevenshteinDistance.Compute(eachWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Key);
            if (score >= 2)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if(used.Add(eachSecondWord.Key)))
            {
                if (!wordSynonymsByLevenstein.ContainsKey(eachWord.Key))
                {
                    wordSynonymsByLevenstein.Add(eachWord.Key, new Dictionary<string, int> { { eachSecondWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Value } });
                }
                else
                {
                    wordSynonymsByLevenstein[eachWord.Key].Add(eachSecondWord.Key, eachSecondWord.Value);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here I used `if(used.Add(eachSecondWord.Key)))` because `Add` will return `true` if the word was added and `false` if it was already in the `HashSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips :) This `Math.Abs` is really help and reduce the time. I change this dictionary to that what you said and get count value from `wordCounter`. Thanks :)